# Get value from JSON array in postgres

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, postgresql-10

I have a strange JSON array in my Postgres Database without curly brackets. It has the datatype Text so i need to cast it in a JSON i guess.

It looks like this and can change from row to row.

```
    [
  [
    "-",
    "name",
    "Gates"
  ],
  [
    "-",
    "name_1",
    null
  ],
  [
    "-",
    "name_2",
    null
  ],
  [
    "-",
    "na_cd",
    null
  ],
  [
    "-",
    "class_cd",
    null
  ],
  [
    "-",
    "reference",
    "190955"
  ],
  [
    "-",
    "lang_cd",
    "en"
  ],
  [
    "-",
    "uid_nr",
    null
  ],
  [
    "-",
    "id",
    19000
  ],
  [
    "-",
    "firstname",
    "Bill"
  ],
  [
    "-",
    "spare",
    null
  ]
]
```

What i need is to find and print the ID if there is one. In this example 19000.

Can someone please help how can do this?

Comment: What if there is more than one array element with `id` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you should use `jsonb_array_elements()` twice, for the main array and for its filtered element (which is an array too).

```sql
select value::numeric as result
from (
    select elem
    from the_data
    cross join jsonb_array_elements(col) as main(elem)
    where elem ? 'id'
    ) s
cross join jsonb_array_elements(elem)
where jsonb_typeof(value) = 'number'
```

Try it in [Db<>Fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e767448105dec9f298be3cc3aad4a804)

However, if you want to get exactly the third value from the nested array, the query may be simpler (note that array elements are indexing from 0):

```sql
select (elem->2)::numeric as result
from the_data
cross join jsonb_array_elements(col) as main(elem)
where elem ? 'id'
```

[Db<>Fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e28e02df360a249bae0037658393187a)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Postgres 12 or later and if the value you are after is always at the third array element, you can use a SQL/JSON path expression:

```
select jsonb_path_query_first(the_column, '$ ? (@[*] == "id")[2]')::int
from the_table
```

This assumes that the column is defined as `jsonb` (which it should be). If it's not, you need to cast it: `the_column::jsonb`

Comment: ERROR: function jsonb_path_query_first(jsonb, unknown) does not exist :(

Comment: @user2210516: I assume you are using a current Postgres version. Which version are you using?

Comment: PostgreSQL 10.18